# datetime vs System.DateTime and ConvertTo-Json in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to capture some file info and store it as JSON.  The problem I'm having is that I end up with 2 kinds of dates that get serialized into JSON differently.

This script ...

```
cd ~
$Index = 'fileInfo.json'
$Members = 'members.txt'

$data = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -First 1 |
    Select-Object -Property CreationTime ,
        @{Name="AsOf";Expression={(Get-Date) -as [datetime]}} 

$data | Get-Member | Out-File $Members
$data | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $Index

#$reloaded = cat $Index | ConvertFrom-Json
```

... produces this JSON

```
{
    "CreationTime":  "\/Date(1423230920315)\/",
    "AsOf":  {
                 "value":  "\/Date(1504713920338)\/",
                 "DisplayHint":  2
             }
}
```

The two dates, CreationTime & AsOf, show as different types:

```
Name         MemberType   Definition                               
----         ----------   ----------                               
AsOf         NoteProperty System.DateTime AsOf=9/6/2017 12:21:30 PM
CreationTime NoteProperty datetime CreationTime=2/6/2015 8:55:20 AM
```

The CreationDate (type 'datetime') gets serialized in a more portable format.

Is there any way to cast the System.dateTime into a 'datetime'??  The '-as datetime' doesn't seem to help.  Thanks

Comment: `AsOf` get wrapped into `PSObject`. It likely because you use `ScriptBlock` `Expression` for `Select-Object` cmdlet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chris, Your question drove me nuts. But after some research, here is what I got. The time that you are getting from the "CreationTime" is actually a time stamp by the NTFS ([link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290(v=vs.85).aspx)) and that is done through C++ at the core. Then when you get time through powershell, it uses the .Net framework when you convert to [datetime]. That's the main difference, and even tho it does say datetime, its not "System.DateTime" because of the different sources.

My solution to your problem is this, if you REALLY want it to be datetime form C++ and not C#.

```
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path .\test123
$Today = Get-Item -Path .\test123 | Select-Object -Property CreationTime
$Creation = Get-ChildItem | Select-Object -First 1 | Select-Object -Property CreationTime
$data = New-Object PSObject
Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name CreationTime -InputObject $data -Value $Creation.CreationTime
Add-Member -type NoteProperty -Name AsOf -InputObject $data -Value $Today.CreationTime
Remove-Item .\test123
```

Comment: Thanks for digging into this.  The explanation helps.